# Corrupted state.yml file on Ansible Molecule test

Tags: ansible, yaml, molecule

On running molecule to test my Ansible changes. I was receiving an error with the state.yml file. As shown:

```
    $ molecule test
 ERROR: while scanning a simple key
   in "/tmp/molecule/my_module/default/state.yml", line 8, column 1
 could not find expected ':'
   in "/tmp/molecule/my_module/default/state.yml", line 9, column 1
 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears on the `state.yml` file had got corrupted on the remove gitlab runner some how. I deleted the file and re-ran the test job, and this passed.